# Tor hidden service isn't working

Tags: onion-services, firefox

I can't use Tor. I'm using an ISP via WiFi in my local town and cannot access some of my favorite .onion addresses. My usual method is that I have profiles in Firefox which allow me to choose to use Firefox incognito before it even begins. I hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `torify firefox`. Then I choose the incognito profile I've setup and then head on over to a .onion address. With this new WiFi network, it appears that nothing is getting through to the Tor network.

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with the network rather than Ubuntu

Comment: Can you access the hidden service of the Tor project: http://idnxcnkne4qt76tg.onion/

Comment: Are you able to access non-Tor sites on the torified versionof firefox? e.g. BBC, CNN, etc? Do you encounter any error messages either in Tor logs or displayed in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

If Tor is being blocked, your Tor instance may not actually be connected to the network. You can review your Tor logs (usually /var/log/tor) to see if it's properly created a circuit.